# Prove that $\sum \frac{i+1}{i!+1}<3$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, induction

> Prove that $$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i+1}{i!+1}<3$$

**My approach:** If $k=1$ we can see that $$S_{1}=\sum_{k=1}^{1}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}=\frac{1+1}{1!+1}=\frac{2}{2}=1<3$$ Now, suppose that the statement is true for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$, it's to say suppose that $S_{n}=\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}<3$ is true, so we need to show that is true for $n+1$, it's to say we need to show that $S_{n+1}=\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}<3$ is also true.

Now, we can see that
\begin{eqnarray*}
S_{n+1}&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n+1}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}\\
&=&\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}+\sum_{k=n+1}^{n+1}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}
\end{eqnarray*}
but, how can I continue from here?

Comment: If you want to go with induction, you need to prove something stronger, like $\sum_{i=0}^k\frac{i+1}{i!+1}<3-\frac1k$ (or something, I don't know whether that specific statement is even true for all $k$). Otherwise, you have no wriggle room in the induction step. (The induction step becomes "I know this thing is less than 3, is this larger thing less than 3?" which is impossible. You want something along the lines of "I know this thing is at least $\frac1k$ away from 3, is this larger thing at least $\frac1{k+1}$ away from 3?")

Comment: I think it would be easiest to estimate in terms of a geometric series. Namely we have $$ \frac{k+1}{k!+1} \leq 2 \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\leq  (1/2)^{k-2}.$$ Using this after $k=3$ should do the trick.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven can you explain me more those inequality? I was thinking use the induction, but I think is more difficult, how can I estimate it using geometric serie?

Comment: @Arthur Ok, so I need to prove something stronger if I want to use induction, right?

Comment: This sum tends to $2.8325652$. Therefore, I suggest you to improve your estimation as follow
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i+1}{i!+1}\approx 2\sqrt{2}+.005
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Arthur points out we cannot directly use induction over the inequality. This is because the summation is an increasing function of $n$ and the upper bound is constant, so if $P(n)<3$ for some constant $n$ then $P(n+1)=P(n)+m<3+m\not<3$ as $m>0$.

We can prove something stronger.

**Claim.** For all $n\in\Bbb N$ we have $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac{i+1}{i!+1}<3-\frac1{n^2}.$$

*Proof.* Let $P(n)$ be the statement in the claim. Evidently $P(1)$ holds so we suppose that $P(k)$ holds for some $k\in\Bbb N$. Then \begin{align}\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k+1}\frac{i+1}{i!+1}=\frac{k+2}{(k+1)!+1}+\sum\limits_{i=1}^k\frac{i+1}{i!+1}<3+\frac{k+2}{(k+1)!+1}-\frac1{k^2}\end{align} so it suffices to show that $$\frac{k+2}{(k+1)!+1}-\frac1{k^2}<-\frac1{(k+1)^2}\impliedby\frac{k+2}{(k+1)!+1}<\frac{2k+1}{k^2(k+1)^2}.$$ Rearranging yields $$(k+1)!>\frac{k^2(k+1)^2(k+2)}{2k+1}-1\impliedby(k-1)!>\frac{(k+1)(k+2)}2$$ which is true for all $k\ge7$ as $(k-1)(k-2)>k+2$ and $k-3>(k+1)/2$. Checking $P(2)$ through $P(6)$ is straightforward and thus $P(n)$ holds for all $n\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: Wow! I love this approach. Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 2):

**Alternative proof without induction:**

Note that $\frac{i+1}{i!+1}$ looks like $\frac{i}{i!} = \frac{1}{(i-1)!}$ and $\sum_{i\ge1}\frac{1}{(i-1)!}=e < 3$. Unfortunately $\frac{i+1}{i!+1}>\frac{i}{i!} $, but we can make some adjustment:

$$\frac{i+1}{i!+1} < \frac{i+1}{i!}=\frac{i+1}{i} \cdot \frac{1}{(i-1)!}$$

Therefore
$$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{i+1}{i!+1} < \frac{1+1}{1!+1}+\frac{2+1}{2!+1}+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\frac{i+1}{i!+1} < 1+1+\sum_{i=3}^\infty\frac{i+1}{i} \cdot \frac{1}{(i-1)!}\\
< 2+ \frac{4}{3}\sum_{i\ge 3}\frac{1}{(i-1)!}=2+\frac 43\cdot (e-2) \approx 2.958 < 3. \blacksquare
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Battle plan (aka hint):**

1.) First show by induction that $k!>2^{k-1}$ for $k\geq 3$.

2.) Then we have for $k\geq 1$

$$ \frac{k+1}{k!+1} \leq \frac{2k}{k!+1} \leq \frac{2k}{k!} = 2 \frac{1}{(k-1)!}.$$

3.) Now write for $n\geq 3$

$$ \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k+1}{k!+1} = 1 + 1 +\sum_{k=3}^n \frac{k+1}{k!+1} 
\leq 2+ \sum_{k=3} \frac{1}{(k-1)!}
<2 + \sum_{k=3}^n (1/2)^{k-2}.$$
Where we used 1.) in the last inequality to estimate by a geometric series. Try to conclude.

Comment: If $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}=2+\sum_{k=3}^{\infty}(1/2)^{k-2}<2+1=3 \implies \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{k+1}{k!+1}<3$?

Comment: Indeed :) that's is the way to go.

Comment: Thank you so much! :)

Comment: Glad I you like it :)